# How does a client establish a peer-to-peer connection?

Tags: networking, client-server, p2p

It is common that (game)clients establish a p2p connection to reduce the latency and the load on the server.

**But how do they do that?**

Here an example: I open my League of Legends client. Press on "Play". Then my client sends the request to the server to find a game. Then the server responds with a list of players (ip addresses?). My client now connects to each player to reduce the ping.

And this is what confuses me. I and many other players are sitting behind a NAT. So maschines from the internet can only send data to my computer if i forward a port on my router or when i send data to a accessible server (open a website, send a request to the game server).

**Me and my opponent have the ip address of each other but we can't connect to each other because our routers are blocking the connection.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia has a description of [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) which gives you an idea how it can be done. The article has some additional links. If nothing else works, the peers have to use a relay.

Comment: do other services like xbox live or torrent use the same technique?